# How to turn off 'on duplicate' statement with use foreign key in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use `GORM Create` function, when I used foreign key, it will automatic generate the 'on duplicate' statement

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name         string
    CompanyRefer int
    Company      Company `gorm:"foreignKey:CompanyRefer; references:CompanyID "`
}

type Company struct {
    CompanyID int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name      string
}
```

sql:

```
INSERT INTO `companies` (`name`,`company_id`) VALUES ('cmy',128) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `company_id`=`company_id`

INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`company_refer`) VALUES ('2022-01-14 17:28:14.849','2022-01-14 17:28:14.849',NULL,'me',128)
```

This leave me with no way to do error handle, is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: No, you can't do that. It is how gorm relations works when creating children data of a relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use gorm.Save,  use gorm.Create function for turn off ON DUPLICATE KEY